# VB 2010 Directory.GetFiles MultipleTypes [NOT A DUPE] The code wont work like the ones everyone tells me

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make it so it scans the computer for multiple files and logs it in a ListBox. That all works except when I get to the multiple types. I have tried almost everything on google.

Needed Code:

```
If (Directory.Attributes <> FileAttributes.System) Then
                    allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("*.png;*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                End If
```

Full Code:

```
Dim tempDir As New DirectoryInfo("C:\")
    Dim FileDetails(4) As String
    Dim iTem As ListViewItem
    Try
        Dim allFiles As FileInfo() = Nothing
        For Each Directory In tempDir.GetDirectories()
            Try
                If (Directory.Attributes <> FileAttributes.System) Then
                    allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("*.png;*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                End If
                Dim oneFIle As FileInfo

                For Each oneFIle In allFiles
                    FileDetails(0) = oneFIle.Name()
                    FileDetails(1) = oneFIle.FullName()
                    FileDetails(2) = oneFIle.Length() / (1024 * 1024)
                    FileDetails(2) = FileDetails(2).Remove(5)
                    iTem = New ListViewItem(FileDetails)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(oneFIle.FullName)
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException

    End Try
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `Directory.GetFiles()` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx), or at the code sample in the linked question?   Your call to `Directory.GetFiles` is missing the **path** argument.  `Directory.Getfiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)`.